# Ciclo de execução de migrations ordenadas no Laravel 5, como altera-lo?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou começando a utilizar esse `framework` e percebi que as `migrations` quando não criadas em um ciclo cronológico para execução pode haver vários erros, isso é normal?

Por exemplo se cria uma `migration` cidade mas ela tem uma `constraint` com uma `migration` de pessoa física porem a `migration` de pessoa física foi criada depois da de cidade ou seja na execução do comando `php artisan migrate` ocorrerá um problema pois a segunda `migration` não estará ativa ainda, esse ciclo que percebi estaria correto?

Se estiver certo esse `framework` é muito baseado em padrões de projeto ou seja, se deve pensar muito bem antes de fazer as coisas, ou tem formas de inverter o processo de criação das `migrations`, exemplo tenho uma `migration` e depois quero inverter alterar a execução dela para antes de outra?

Comment: Não entendo muito de Laravel, mas pelo que disse a lógica é que uma coisa é amarrada na outra, semelhante a chave estrangeira, então basicamente a resposta é sim, precisa projetar antes de começar a "criar", claro que dá pra fazer os dois ao mesmo tempo mas é necessário ter uma noção de como projetar. Logo alguém que entende de Laravel aparece pra responder com mais detalhes :)

Comment: Eu acho que as migrations do laravel tinha que ser igual a do cakephp: Você pode executar uma específica.